# Applozic register user ios

Tags: ios, swift, chat, applozic

I created app in Applozic, I got AppKey etc. but when I tried to register user I constantly get error: invalid password

here is my code:

```
 let alUser : ALUser =  ALUser()
    alUser.userId = "someuserid"     // NOTE : +,*,? are not allowed chars in userId.
    alUser.email = "abcdef@gmail.com"
    alUser.imageLink = ""                                // User's profile image link.
    alUser.displayName = "abcName"      // User's Display Name
    alUser.password = "Abc321123"
//    alUser.authenticationTypeId = 0

    ALUserDefaultsHandler.setUserId(alUser.userId)
    ALUserDefaultsHandler.setEmailId(alUser.email)
    ALUserDefaultsHandler.setDisplayName(alUser.displayName)
    ALUserDefaultsHandler.setPassword(alUser.password)
 //   ALUserDefaultsHandler.setUserAuthenticationTypeId(alUser.authenticationTypeId)

    let chatManager = ALChatManager(applicationKey: "31fb06a4a5c44509cb76bdebbf96afd51")


    chatManager.registerUser(alUser) { (response, error) in

        if (error == nil)
        {
            //Applozic registration successful
        } else {
            print("Error in Applozic registration : ",error!.description);
        }
    }
}
```

and response:

```
RESPONSE_USER_REGISTRATION :: {
currentTimeStamp = 1513038440083;
deactivate = 0;
message = "INVALID_PARAMETER";
totalUnreadCount = 0;}
```

I set appkey also in ALChatManager.swift - applicationId

Comment: Are you getting INVALID_PARAMETER or invalid password in logs ? can you share the complete logs in text file

Answer (score 0):

Try this and check web dashboard...

```
 let user = ALUser()
user.userId = str_user_id
    user.displayName = first_name + " " + last_name
    user.imageLink =  str_Url
    ALUserDefaultsHandler.setUserId(user.userId)
    ALUserDefaultsHandler.setDisplayName(user.displayName)

    let demoChatManager = ALChatManager.init()
    demoChatManager.register(user)
```